Permutest or TukeyHSD for group-wise comparison after significant Anova of betadisper?
I want to perform a PERMANOVA with my community-data of spider assembladges, sampled in different forest stands. Before applying PERMANOVA I wanted to find out if there is a difference in the dispersion between the groups.
For that I used betadisper
dispersion_stands_trap <- 
    betadisper(all_dist_trap, 
    meta_distance_trap$stand)

This returns a significant output
> anova(dispersion_stands_trap)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Distances
           Df Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
Groups      4 0.2124 0.053107  2.4785 0.04653 *
Residuals 149 3.1927 0.021427                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

In order to interpret my data correctly, I want to know which groups excactly differ in their dispersion.
I read that I can use TukeyHSD or permutest to perform a pairwise comparison.
permutest(dispersion_stands_trap, 
    pairwise=TRUE)

returns the following:
Pairwise comparisons:
(Observed p-value below diagonal, permuted p-value above diagonal)
           D        DB         B        FB     F
D            0.1450000 0.0980000 0.0030000 0.399
DB 0.1502930           0.8250000 0.1040000 0.558
B  0.0987879 0.8288240           0.1640000 0.425
FB 0.0035463 0.1172937 0.1621860           0.026
F  0.3962535 0.5326374 0.3977593 0.0291775

but when I use
TukeyHSD(dispersion_stands_trap)

the significant comparisons change (loss of significant effect F-FB):
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = distances ~ group, data = df)

$group
              diff          lwr        upr     p adj
DB-D   0.060699868 -0.042825680 0.16422542 0.4875989
B-D    0.068575786 -0.036690784 0.17384236 0.3780614
FB-D   0.112144505  0.009417572 0.21487144 0.0248321
F-D    0.036470261 -0.066256672 0.13919719 0.8637376
B-DB   0.007875918 -0.096552782 0.11230462 0.9995769
FB-DB  0.051444637 -0.050423540 0.15331281 0.6321060
F-DB  -0.024229607 -0.126097784 0.07763857 0.9651200
FB-B   0.043568719 -0.060068327 0.14720576 0.7735077
F-B   -0.032105525 -0.135742571 0.07153152 0.9124905
F-FB  -0.075674244 -0.176730709 0.02538222 0.2395908


This leads me to the questions on which of those two tests I should rely?
I have a slightly unbalanced desing
D 30,
DB 31,
B 29,
FB 32,
F 32
might that be problematic?

Both the anova() output, the "Observed" pairwise p values, and Tukey's HSD   are making certain statistical assumptions that are, to greater or lesser extent likely violated in the test of homogeneity of multivariate dispersions.
The pairwise p values are also subject to multiple comparisons problems. Hence the Tukey HSD, which is used to control the family-wise error rate to be $1 - \alpha$. Of the standard statistical summaries, I would use the Tukey HSD results, but note that this makes assumptions about the distributions of group means compared.
In place of anova() I would use permutest() to get a permutation-based omnibus test.
The pairwise permutation p values are OK, but you should correct them for multiple comparisons; you could pass the set of p values to p.adjust() an  choose one of the adjustment methods; "fdr" would control the false discovery rate for example:
pp <- permutest(dispersion_stands_trap, pairwise=TRUE)
p.adjust(pp$pairwise$permuted, method = "fdr")

